# stream reader second line visual studio c#

Tags: c#, streamreader, readline

I'm using this method to save my connection sentence into a text file:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

byte[] memData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";" + Environment.NewLine + "Initial Catalog=" + textBox2.Text + ";" + Environment.NewLine + "User ID=" + textBox3.Text + ";" + Environment.NewLine + "password=" + textBox4.Text + ";");

ms.Write(memData, 0, memData.Length);
FileStream strm = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Çağatay\Desktop\test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
ms.WriteTo(strm);
ms.Close();
strm.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Connection Saved");
```

Is there a method for reloading lines to textboxes back with streamreader?

I searched and found this:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Çağatay\Desktop\test.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(line);
    counter++;
}

file.Close();
```

But I need something like:

```
textbox1.text=streamreader.readline[0]
textbox2.text=streamreader.readline[1]
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Any reason you wouldn't just load the whole file?

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Çağatay\Desktop\test.txt");
```

Likewise your first piece of code would be considerably simpler with:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    @"C:\Users\Çağatay\Desktop\test.txt",
    new[]
    {
        "Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";",
        "Initial Catalog=" + textBox2.Text + ";", 
        "User ID=" + textBox3.Text + ";",
        "password=" + textBox4.Text + ";"
    });
```

Or with C# 6:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    @"C:\Users\Çağatay\Desktop\test.txt",
    new[]
    {
        $"Data Source={textBox1.Text};",
        $"Initial Catalog={textBox2.Text};",
        $"User ID={textBox3.Text};",
        $"password={textBox4.Text};"
    });
```

Comment: I think it's so he can map lines to text boxes. Then again, with your code he can do `textbox1.Text = lines[0]`

Comment: how can i attach first line to textbox1.text and line 2 to textbox2.text?

Comment: @CagatayCelik: `textBox1.Text = lines[0]; textBox2.Text = lines[1];`... it's just an array.

Comment: thats good thank you and one more question 
when it reads Data Source=****; comes but i only want *** part is it possible?

Comment: can we get **** part from textfile?

Comment: @CagatayCelik: If you don't want `Data Source=` then don't write it out to the file...

Comment: oh you are right. Thank you so much for help its solved (Y)